# MYSQL update rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is an a small sample of my very large example table. I am trying to identify the max sprint by grouping the feature that have multiple sprint. After I've identified them, I want to update the review column with a value.

TEST_TABLE

```
Feature   |  Sprint  |  Review 
-------------------------------
Code001   |  100     |
Code002   |  100     |
Code001   |  101     |
Code003   |  100     |
Code003   |  100     |
Code004   |  101     |
```

MY QUERY:

```
SELECT feature, MAX(sprint), review
FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE feature IN (select feature 
                  from TEST_TABLE
                  GROUP BY feature
                  HAVING COUNT(distinct sprint)>1
                 )
GROUP BY feature
```

RESULTS:

```
Feature   | Max(sprint)| Review
--------------------------------
Code001   |  101       |
```

QUESTION: The above query selects the correct results but I do not know how to update the review column. I want my results to look like this at the end after I have updated the review column.

TEST_TABLE

```
Feature   |  Sprint  |  Review 
-------------------------------
Code001   |  100     |
Code002   |  100     |
Code001   |  101     | Feature File Modified
Code003   |  100     |
Code003   |  100     |
Code004   |  101     |
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your sample query does really make sense.  It uses `MAX()` with no `GROUP BY`, for instance.  You need to be clearer on sample data and desired results.

Comment: And is syntactically incorrect

Comment: Also you have not shown any code that in any way relates to updating the `Review` column

Comment: SELECT feature, MAX(sprint), review
FROM test_20170116
WHERE feature IN (select feature 
from test_20170116
GROUP BY feature
HAVING COUNT(sprint)>1)

Comment: My question is how do I write an update to get to my end result. I am stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your select query does not make sense, as @GordonLinoff also pointed out. Without providing that clarification, it is unlikely that you will get any useful answers.

Comment: I corrected my mistake in my select statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update *all* such features, you can use:

```
update test_table tt join
       (select feature 
        from TEST_TABLE
        group by feature
        having count(distinct sprint) > 1
       ) ttt
       on ttt.feature = tt.feature
    set tt.review = 'Feature File Modified';
```

That is not quite what is in your example.  You seem to want all but the "first" to be modified.  I think this goes as:

```
update test_table tt join
       (select feature , min(sprint) as minsprint
        from TEST_TABLE
        group by feature
        having count(distinct sprint) > 1
       ) ttt
       on tt.feature = ttt.feature and
          tt.sprint > ttt.minsprint
    set tt.review = 'Feature File Modified';
```

Comment: The above query almost gets what I am looking for. The issue is that the sprint in my example may not be just 100 and 101. What if a feature had 100, 101, and 102... the above update would update the Review row of 101 and 102 when I am only to update 102.

Comment: I was able to fix it by modifying the above code. This resolves my issue: update TEST_TABLE tt join
       (select feature , max(sprint) as maxsprint
        from TEST_TABLE
        group by feature
        having count(distinct sprint) > 1
       ) ttt
       on tt.feature = ttt.feature and
          tt.sprint = ttt.maxsprint
    set tt.review = 'Feature File Modified';